# Отправка сообщений из delphi кода

Tags: delphi

Есть ли возможность отправлять HTML сообщения?

```
idSMTP1.Host:='smtp.mail.ru';
idSMTP1.Port:=25;
idSMTP1.Username:='Логин';
idSMTP1.Password:='пароль';
idMessage1.Body.Text:='Текст';
idMessage1.From.Text:=idSMTP1.Username+'@mail.ru';
idMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses:='qwerty@mail.ru';
idMessage1.Subject:='Fake ';

idSMTP1.Connect();
if idSMTP1.Connected=true then
idSMTP1.send(idMessage1) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.ru/search?q=idsmtp+delphi+html первая ссылка